# Regular expression substitution in sublime text

Tags: regex, string, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a lot of strings to edit and replace with the support of regular expression.

My strings are like:

```
'word1 'word2 word3'
'axxx' 'bx bxxxxx'
```

and so on.

What I need to do is selecting the last part of the line and replicate it again, so basically what I want to do is:

```
'word1' 'word2 word3'
```

becomes:
'word1' 'word2 word3' 'word2 word3'

What I tried is: take the last part included in the '' and replicate it, but it doesn't work: I tried this substitution.

```
'(\w+)'$  ->  '$1' '$1'
```

but no match is highlighted.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
('[^']+')$
```

And replace with `$1 $1`

Explanation:

- `('` start capture group 1.. followed by `'` (quote)
- `[^']+` Match everything other than `'`
- `')$` match `'` .. close the capture group followed by end of string

This will match the text within `' '` which is at the end of the string.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nX9vQ7/2)